# Deterministic finite automaton algorithm

Tags: computer-science, automata

I am having a little trouble understanding this question.

For a DFA M = (Q, Σ, δ, q0, F), we say that a state q ∈ Q is reachable if there
exists some string w ∈ Σ∗ such that q = δ∗(q0, w).

Give an algorithm that, given as input a DFA expressed as a five-tuple M =
(Q, Σ, δ, q0, F), returns the set of all of M’s reachable states.

Can anyone help me understand and answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

Someone hands you a DFA $M=\langle Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F\rangle$, i.e., a set of states, an input alphabet, a transition function, an initial state, and a set of acceptor states. You’re to come up with an algorithm — a systematic procedure — that takes this information as input and produces as output a list of the reachable states of $M$.

A first easy observation is that you can ignore $F$ altogether: you don’t care which states are accepting, just which ones can actually be reached from $q_0$ with some input. You will need to use the other four items, however. A second easy observation is that $q_0$ is reachable, since $\delta^*(q_0,\epsilon)=q_0$, where $\epsilon$ is the empty word.

If $\Sigma=\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$, the natural thing to do is to start by running $M$ with all $n$ one-symbol inputs; that will tell you which states are reachable in one transition. Then you could systematically test inputs of length $2$:

$$\sigma_1\sigma_1,\sigma_1\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_1\sigma_n,\sigma_2\sigma_1,\sigma_2\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_2\sigma_n,\ldots,\sigma_n\sigma_n\;.$$

And you could go on to longer and longer inputs. The only real question is how to know when to stop: at what point can you be sure that you’ve found all of the reachable states?

HINT: If there are $m$ states, how long a word must you input in order to guarantee that the DFA will visit some state twice while reading the word?

Comment: Can you please explain the hint for me ? thanks

Comment: @Elaqqad: You start in $q_0$. If each new input causes you to change state, after $n$ inputs you will have visited $n+1$ states. If $n+1>m$, you must have visited some state twice. Thus, reading a word of length $m$ ensures that you’ll visit some state twice.

Answer (score -1):

I hope that this algorithm will be useful for you:

```
algorithm: determine the set if reachable states of an DFA;
   intput: an DFA M = (Q, Σ, δ, q0, F);
   output: an list of reachable state;
   begin
      create a list result and insert q0;
      create a stack s and push q0;
      while s is not empty
         do
            q = pop(s);
            if q != q0 then
               insert q in result;
            for each symbol a of Σ
               do
                  q' = δ(q, a);
                  if q' does not belongs to result then
                     push(s,q');
               done
            done
      return result;
   end.
```